# How to list all the cobol programs in a project in mainframe ispf

Tags: cobol, mainframe, ispf

I need to view all the source codes available in a project. In which utility can I list all the source codes

Comment: What change mamagement system do you use? ChangeMan? Else?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is it depends on your source control manager.  On the mainframe there are storage mechanisms for source and a common one is a Partitioned Dataset (PDS).  These you can easily access through ISPF option 2 which is generally edit unless your site has changed the panels.

Other ways to do broader searches for datasets can be found on Option 3 `=3<enter>` to see the utilities.  Option 3.4 is good for searching for datasets based on name.  From here you could `edit` the file and see its members.  If your familiar with Linux you’ll recall that *nix and Windows use a folder structure emanating from the root of the file system.  z/OS datasets are a little different although conceptually they are similar.

If your shop uses `Git` then you would look for the files in GIT and would not likely use ISPF edit.

There are other proprietary source and build management systems from a variety of vendors.  Some include `Endevor`, `Changeman`, `Librarian` Might still be around but its fairly old.

Your question is too broad to provide a specific answer but hopefully this will give you some pointers to further your quest.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using EPDF command to access the dataset directly and view the components and the below link will help you in understanding more about the command.

https://ibmmainframes.com/about26084.html

Regards,
Anbu.